# How to get the output of a command

Tags: go, exec

I am calling a python script from Go code:

```
package main
import (
    "os/exec"
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("python","/home/devendra/Desktop/sync/blur_multithread.py","http://4.imimg.com/data4/TP/ED/NSDMERP-28759633/audiovideojocks.png")
    var logs=make(map[string]interface{})
    logs["tes"]=os.Stdout
    _ = cmd.Run()   
    WriteLogs(logs)//Writelog is my function which logs everything in a file
}

func WriteLogs(logs map[string]interface{}){
  currentTime := time.Now().Local()
  jsonLog, err := json.Marshal(logs)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
  }

  jsonLogString := string(jsonLog[:len(jsonLog)])
  logfile := "/home/devendra/ImageServiceLogs/"+ "ImageServiceLogs_" + currentTime.Format("2006-01-02") + ".txt"
  if logfile == "" {
    fmt.Println("Could not find logfile in configuration ...!!!")
  } else {

    jsonLogFile, err := os.OpenFile(logfile, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0644)
    defer jsonLogFile.Close()
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    jsonLogFile.WriteString(jsonLogString + "\n")
  }
}
```

But in the logs value of tes field is null while my python script is giving me output. How to get the output of python script in my code?

Comment: The problem is in WriteLogs. Nevertheless: Use Cmd.CombinedOutput, that is probably more what you want.

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/20909764/4466350

Comment: Note that os.Stdout is an io.Writer. Note second that os.Stdout has nothing to do with the command you run directly. Then think about what encoding/json.Marshal does with a io.Writer. I warm hearted recommend you to do the Tour of Go once more focusing on types and how they behave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per official documentation examples, `exec.Cmd.Ouput() ([]byte, error)` will give you the sdout of the command after it has finished running.

https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Output

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    out, err := exec.Command("date").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("The date is %s\n", out)
}
```

To receive both stdout and stderr of the process, writer should use `exec.Cmd.CombinedOutput`
https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.CombinedOutput

If someone wants to receive the command output in real time to its terminal, then the writer should set `exec.Cmd.Stdout` and `exec.Cmd.Stderr` properties to, respectively, `os.Stdout` and `os.Stderr` and invoke the `exec.Cmd.Run() error` method.

https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd
https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Run

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("date")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("The date is %s\n", out)
}
```

To forward outputs and capture it at the same time, writer should seek help of the `io` package to use an `io.MultiWriter`

https://golang.org/pkg/io/#MultiWriter

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    stdout := new(bytes.Bufer)
    stderr := new(bytes.Bufer)
    cmd := exec.Command("date")
    cmd.Stdout = io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, stdout)
    cmd.Stderr = io.MultiWriter(os.Stderr, stderr)
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("The date is %s\n", out)
}
```

Alternatively, you can make use of the `exec.Cmd.{Stdout,Stderr}Pipe()` see the official documentation examples https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.StdoutPipe